# Python Panel DashBoard: FileSelector not updating the selected file

Tags: python, panel

I am trying to create simple dashboard where when user select from the any directory, he can able to view its details (df.head()) details. But somehow, when I select other file its not rendering and provide updated results.

Here's code that I am trying :

```
files_dir = r'C:\\Users\\navee\\Desktop\\GL'
file_selected = pn.widgets.FileSelector(files_dir)

if len(file_selected.value) == 0:
    file_selected.value = ['C:\\Users\\navee\\Desktop\\GL\\Book1.csv']

@pn.depends(file_selected.param.value, watch=True)
def get_df(file_selected):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_selected[0])
    return print(df.head())

pn.Column(file_selected, get_df)
```

Also I am adding if condition, so the code will not fail at first instance. Are there any other way workaround for it.

Thanks.